# Promise not resolving data in Jasmine test - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I have a service making reverse geocoding (translate coordinates into an address), and I use a promise to get the result.

When I try to test it, it does not resolve data even if I call the digest loop on the rootscope and it returns the test is passed even if conditions can't be satisfied.

Here it is the test file

```
'use strict';

describe('revGeocodeService', function () {

    var revGeocodeService;
    var resultAdd = "";

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('angularApp');
    });

    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_revGeocodeService_, _$rootScope_) {
        revGeocodeService = _revGeocodeService_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it('should reverse position to an address', function () {
        var position = {};
        position.latitude = 51.5310315;
        position.longitude = -0.06899029999999999;


        revGeocodeService.getAddress(position).then(function (result) {
            resultAdd = result;
            expect(1).toBe('somevalue');
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });

});
```

and here it is the service

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    var revGeocodeService = function ($q) {
        return {
            getAddress: function (position) {
                console.log(position.latitude + " " + position.longitude);
                //set up the promise
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                // set up the Geocoder object
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                // turn coordinates into an object
                var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

                // find out info about our location
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': yourLocation
                }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                            // return results[0].formatted_address;
                            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                            deferred.resolve(results[0].formatted_address);

                        } else {
                            error('Google did not return any results.');
                            deferred.resolve(null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        error("Reverse Geocoding failed due to: " + status);
                        deferred.resolve(null);
                    }


                });

                return deferred.promise;

            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('angularApp').factory('revGeocodeService', ['$q', revGeocodeService]);

}());
```

Comment: google.maps will need to be injected in to the service as a dependency so you can mock it to return results for your unit test

Comment: Thanks, they are already included in my karma.conf.js file, do I need to include it in the test file? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: What I meant was your service should be declared as `var revGeocodeService = function ($q, google) ` so you can then mock google in your tests

Comment: I have just tried, nothing happens, the test returns success even if it should be failed.

Comment: I'll provide an example shortly

Comment: thank you very much, I'll wait for it